# Determine whether each of $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let

$V_1=\{(x,y,z,w)\space|\space x-y+z=2w\}$

$V_2=\{(x,y,z,w)\space|\space xyz=2w\}$

$V_3=\{(x,y,z,w)\space|\space x-y+z=2^w\}$

(a) Determine whether each of $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Justify.

Answer: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are rather obvious that the zero vector are present in both and not in the $V_3$. Hence the latter is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

How do i show Closure under scalar multiplication and Closure under addition? (P.S. I'm pretty sure $V_1$ is.

(b) Find a basis for and determine the dimension of the subspaces among  $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$. (i.e. you only need to do this for those $V_i$ that are subspaces)

Answer: how do i pull out vectors from equations?

I'm rather new to Linear Algebra btw if it wasn't clear.

Comment: To show the closure: take $x_1 - y_1 + z_1 - 2w_1,x_2 - y_2 + z_2 - 2w_2 \mathbb{R}$ add the two together you will see that they are in $V_1$ and multiply them together to see if they are also in $V_1$ if they are then they satisfy the closure property.

Comment: @MorganWeiss Multiply them together? I think you mean take an arbitrary vector in $V_{1}$ and multiply it by an arbitrary scalar and check if it is in $V_{1}$.  It's meaningless to say that we "multiply" two vectors together.

Comment: Yes, my apologies I wasn't clear there

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'll show you for $V_{1}$.

Suppose we have vectors $(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}, w_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2}, z_{2}, w_{2})$ in $V_{1}$.  We want to check if $(x_{1} + x_{2}, y_{1} + y_{2}, z_{1} + z_{2}, w_{1} + w_{2})$ is in $V_{1}$ to check if it is closed under addition.

That means we need this new vector to satisfy that the first coordinate minus the second plus the third equals $2$ times the fourth, i.e., $x_{1} + x_{2} - (y_{1} + y_{2}) + z_{1} + z_{2} = 2(w_{1} + w_{2})$.  Is this true?

Well, $(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}, w_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2}, z_{2}, w_{2})$ are both in $V_{1}$, so we know $x_{1} - y_{1} + z_{1} = 2w_{1}$ and $x_{2} - y_{2} + z_{2} = 2w_{2}$.  If we add these two equations together, we get:

\begin{alignat} {2}
& \phantom{+}x_{1} - y_{1} + z_{1} = 2w_{1} \\ 
+ &  \\ 
& \phantom{+}x_{2} - y_{2} + z_{2} = 2w_{2} \\ 
& \text{______________________} && \\  
& x_{1} + x_{2} - y_{1} - y_{2} + z_{1} + z_{2} &&={} 2w_{1} + 2w_{2} 
\end{alignat}

But that's the same equation as $x_{1} + x_{2} - (y_{1} + y_{2}) + z_{1} + z_{2} = 2(w_{1} + w_{2})$, so the vector $(x_{1} + x_{2}, y_{1} + y_{2}, z_{1} + z_{2}, w_{1} + w_{2})$ satisfies what it needs to to be in $V_{1}$, so $V_{1}$ is closed under addition.

Now check that it is closed under scalar multiplication, and do these same things to check if $V_{2}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Ok i done all that and i found only $V_1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is that right?

Answer (score 0):

a) $V_{1}$ represents a plane in through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, so it is a subspace, as you know.

For $V_{2}$, consider the vector $(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2},1)$ that satisfies the equation.  If you add this to itself, does it give a vector in $V_{2}$, i.e. does $(2\sqrt[3]{2})^{3} = 2\times 2$?

For $V_{3}$, consider the vector $(1,1,1,0)$ that satisfies the equation.  If you add this to itself, does it give a vector in $V_{3}$, i.e. does $2 - 2 + 2 = 2^{0}$?  (You already know this isn't a subspace, so this is just another argument)

b) For a basis for $V_{1}$, note that every vector $(x, y, z, w)$ has the form:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
y - z  + 2w \\
y\\
z\\
w \\
\end{array} \right)
$$
so what 3 vectors is this a linear combination of, i.e. for what 3 vectors $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$ is this equal to $yv_{1} + zv_{2} + wv_{3}$?

Comment: alright i did that and found that only $V_1$ is a subspace of $/mathbb{R}^4$. is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right.